# Pasar javascript variable a php

Tags: php, html, html-select

```html
<?php
$connexio = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($connexio, 'controlPresencia');
$dni = "";
$dia = "";
if (isset($_GET["miselector"])) {
    $dni = $_GET['miselector'];
    $query = "select distinct dia from faltes where dni='$dni'";
    $prova = mysqli_query($connexio, $query);

    echo '<form action="eliminarIncidencia.php">';
    echo '<select id="dia" name="dia">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prova)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['dia'] . '">' . $row['dia'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</form>';
    $_GET['miselector'] = null;
} elseif (isset($_GET["dia"])) {
    $dia = $_GET['dia'];
    echo $dia;
} else {
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#miselector").on("change", function() {
                    $.get("eliminarIncidencia.php?miselector=" + this.value, function(result) {
                        $("#returned").html(result);
                    });
                });

                $("#dia").on("change", function() {
                    $.get("eliminarIncidencia.php?dia=" + this.value, function(result) {
                        $("#table").html(result);
                    });
                });
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {});
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php
        $query = "select * from usuari";
        $prova = mysqli_query($connexio, $query);
        echo '<form action="eliminarIncidencia.php">';
        echo '<select id="miselector" name="miselector">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prova)) {
            echo '<option value="' . $row['dni'] . '">' . $row['nom'] . ' ' . $row['cognom'] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
        echo '</form>';
        ?>

        <div id="returned" style="background-color:red;">
            aqui cambiara el contenido seleccionado
        </div>

        <div id="table" style="background-color:blue;">
            dia
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
<?php } ?>
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function crearDies() {
        var dni = document.getElementById('usuari').value;
        <?php
        $var_PHP = "<script>document.writeln(dni);</script>"; 
        echo $var_PHP;
        ?>
    }
</script>


    <?php
    $query = "select * from usuari";
    $prova = mysqli_query($connexio, $query);
    echo '<select id="usuari" onchange="crearDies()">';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prova)) {
        echo '<option value="' . $row['dni'] . '">' . $row['nom'] . ' ' . $row['cognom'] . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>

    <div id="selectDies"></div>
```

La idea es que con el valor de $var_PHP hare consulta mysql para crear otro select dentro del div "selectDies", con lo cual no se si hay una solucion que no tenga que recargar la pagina.
He visto alguna solucion con ajax pero recarga la pagina y quiero que el primer select mantenga el valor que tenia.

Edit: He conseguido que el primer select me haga aparecer el segundo pero el segundo no me hace nada, no se si es por poner las dos funciones como las pongo o porque no esta bien estructurado el php con el $_GET, ya que no lo he usado nunca y no se muy bien como va

Comment: Con Ajax lo puedes hacer.

Comment: Sin recargar la pagina?, es que todo lo que veo dice que envia a otra pagina

Comment: Si, puedes utilizar jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres realizar realizar dos o más consultas puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$query = "SELECT (SELECT columna
                  FROM tabla)
                  AS renombrar_tabla,
                  (SELECT columna
                  FROM tabla_2)
                  AS renombrar_tabla_2,
                  (SELECT columna
                  FROM tabla_3)
                  AS renombrar_tabla_3";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: Me he explicado mal, lo que el codigo tendria que hacer es que empieza creando un <select> dinamico con conexion a base de dados, despues escojo un valor y me crea otro <select> para escoger otro valor y con los dos valores haria una tercera consulta a base de datos.

Comment: Si tienes valores que dependan de otros para ser mostrados lo que puedes hacer es incluir una función "toggle" que lo que hace es mostrar/esconder un elemento, pero agregándole un condicional IF que compruebe si el valor esperado fue reconocido o no.

Answer (score 0):

Con estos 3 archivos puede usar un selector para elegir qué datos cargar en otro selector que se mostrará dentro de un div

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se selecciona un elemento en el selector (index.php), se dispara un ajax (index.js), que envía qué elemento se seleccionó, se llama la página dies.php, verifica qué valor se seleccionó y, en función de eso, se crea otro selector de acuerdo con los datos pasado tendrá uno o una lista de valores (dies.php), después de eso, el javascript inserta este nuevo selector dentro del div (index.js)

**dies.php**

```php
<?php
        $die = $_POST['die'];
        $query = "select * from usuari";

        //reemplace las líneas que creé con la llamada mysql

        $fila1 = ["midia"=>"Lunes","nom"=>"yo","cognom"=>"tu",];
        $fila2 = ["midia"=>"Martes","nom"=>"el","cognom"=>"es",];
        $fila3 = ["midia"=>"Miércoles","nom"=>"los","cognom"=>"las",];
        $fila4 = ["midia"=>"Jueves","nom"=>"mi","cognom"=>"perro",];
        $filas = array($fila1, $fila2, $fila3, $fila4);
        echo '<select id="usuari">';
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < sizeof($filas)) {
            $row = $filas[$i];

            //filtrado en sql, no necesitará esto if

            if($die==$row['midia']){
                echo '<option value="' . $row['midia'] . '">' . $row['nom'] . ' ' . $row['cognom'] . '</option>';
            }
            $i++;
        }
        echo '</select>';
?>
```

**index.php**

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="Dies" onchange="crearDies()">
        <option value="Lunes">Lunes</option>
        <option value="Martes">Martes</option>
        <option value="Miércoles">Miércoles</option>
        <option value="Jueves">Jueves</option>
        <option value="Viernes">Viernes</option>
        <option value="Sábado">Sábado</option>
        <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
    </select>
    <div id="selectDies"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
function crearDies() {
    let die = document.getElementById("Dies").value;
    $.post("dies.php", {die: die },
        function(result){
            $('#selectDies').empty();
            $('#selectDies').append(result);
            console.log('<p>'+result+'</p>');
        }).fail(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar a grandes rasgos qué hace el código que has puesto?

Comment: @ordago, yo mejoré la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Al final use esto:

```
 function prueba1() {
            var xhttp;
            xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                document.getElementById("taula").innerHTML="";
                document.getElementById("segundoSelect").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            };
            xhttp.open("GET", "getSelect.php?q=" + document.getElementById('miselector').value, true);
            xhttp.send();
    }
```

Poniendo esa funcion en el select pertinente me ejecuta el getselect.php que me retorna lo que necesito